# Populating a CSV file through looping over lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wanted to generate a CSV file for machine learning processing. I have various files which I am going to use to make a unified file by looping over these files. I am trying to overcome the duplicates issues when the dictionaries are used.

```
data_dict= {} for mol in molecules: # molecules contain mol1, mol2 ... and each mol has atom1, atom2, atom3 .... 
data_dict[mol] = {} 
molecular_system = read("trajectories")  
hf = ChargeAnalysisTechnique() 
for atom, charge in zip(molecular_system, hf.get_charges()): 
    sym = atom.symbol 
    atom.charge = charge 
    data_dict[mol][sym] = sym 
    data_dict[mol][sym]["x_coord"] = atom.position[0] 
    data_dict[mol][sym]["y_coord"] = atom.position[1] 
    data_dict[mol][sym]["z_coord"] = atom.position[2] 
    data_dict[mol][sym]["Hirshfeld_charge"] = charge

np.save("myDataBase.npy", data_dict)
```

I want to output a table like the following:

[image]

I tried to use dictionaries but I cannot work it out, duplicates are removed from the generated npy file.

Comment: Maybe you should adjust your code formatting first.

Comment: I hope it looks better now!

Comment: I think for hierarchical data such as molecules, you might be better off using a structured data format such as a `yaml` or `json` file. This will directly work with python `dict`s like you populate with the `data_dict` dictionary. If you need  CSV files, it's probably best to work with one molecule per file. Also, please note that `np.save` does not work for anything but Numpy arrays (and not `dict`s).